# In House of Suns, what was the role played by Dr Meninx?

Tags: alastair-reynolds

That is, what was his role in the larger context of the story? Was he just a character to be sacrificed to temporarily cast doubt on Hesperus? Or was he just meant to be an example of the fact that different societies were studying the Vigilance?

Comment: If you ask me, he's just one example of the deep problems with that book, and indeed with Reynolds's writing generally. What was the point of the flashbacks about the game, for that matter? Reynolds has cool ideas but never really manages to tie them down into a proper structured plot.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I can't seem to find it right now, but I read an answer here saying that the Palatial flashbacks were an allegory of how the Lines eventually exterminated the First Machines, and that made sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hesperus's nature is a major plot point, so it's not inconceivable to create and then sacrifice a character to create drama around it. In addition to that, the good doctor's presence gives us insight into the role the shatterlings are playing in galactic affairs. Providing safe transport is one of the services they offer that helps keep them influential among the more transient civilizations. Further, Meninx's oft expressed distrust also gives us an external view of our pov characters.